# Create texstudio macro to open file from tex tree

Tags: texstudio

`texstudio` has the nice ability to open included files from within another file by right click on the file name

```
\include{test}
```

and then `open test` from the context menu
[image]

This works for files which are either in the current working folder or for which a relative or absolute path is specified. It does not work for files which are within the search path of latex.

---

## Question:

Is it possible to create a user macro (or similar) to open a file from the latex search path?

From the command line, I'd use

```
open `kpsewhich ushyphex.tex`
```

to open them. I tried to write a texstudio user macro

```
%SCRIPT
system(open `kpsewhich cursor.selectedText()`);
```

(and for simplicity had `.tex` included in the selected text) however this leads to an error

[image]

Comment: Does it work if you enclose the `open ...` in quotes?

Comment: @Troy Thanks for your suggestion. Please see my edit - it seems that the ` now  are not properly recognised and `open` tries to open two separate files...

Comment: It doesn't answer the question, but I take the ability of TS to do so is already build in somehow. When an error is indicated in compilation in a line within a package with a click you get the sty or whatever the case is to open. I have no idea how to exploit this for the purpose, but perhaps someone else has...

Comment: @gusbrs I did not check the source code, but I imagine this could also be done via clever parsing of the log file which contains the absolute path.

Comment: @gusbrs However the texstudio source code seems to include some interesting fuctions, e.g. `KpathSeaParser` ....

Comment: Yes, I suppose the "macro" you want must be somehow included in the source code. But that's a hunch...

Comment: @gusbrs Too bad I can no longer compile texstudio from source (my qt version is too old). It seems hacking the original open function would be much easier then creating a user script :(

Comment: Well, that might be arranged if you think it's worth it. Still, I'm out of my depth on the matter. Let's hope someone else shows up with more ideas.

Comment: @gusbrs Good to hear! It is not really urgent, so I have time to wait and see if someone comes up with an answer. I also made a feature request for texstudio. Let's see.

Comment: Try this: `buildManager.runCommand("open \"kpsewhich ushyphex.tex\"","");`

Comment: It seems the shell has to be explicitly called. I'm not sure what it is for Mac, but the one for Linux is `sh -c`. So something like `system(sh -c '<your shell cmd>')` should work? I don't have a mac so I can't try it out

Comment: Note to myself: `system("open /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyphenex/ushyphex.tex");` works fine

Comment: @tomacs Thanks for your comment! I get `Process started: open "kpsewhich ushyphex.tex"

The file /kpsewhich ushyphex.tex does not exist.`. The command `open "kpsewhich ushyphex.tex"` also fails if executed directly in terminal. I tried to replace \" with \\`, but this gives `Process started: open `kpsewhich ushyphex.tex`

The files /`kpsewhich and /ushyphex.tex` do not exist.`

Comment: @Troy I tried with `system("sh -c 'open /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyphenex/ushyphex.tex'");` (which works fine in terminal) and I get `Process started: sh -c 'open /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyphenex/ushyphex.tex'

/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyphenex/ushyphex.tex': -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `'' /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyphenex/ushyphex.tex': -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
`. Same error with \` instead of '

Comment: @samcarter gah.. Can you try `system('sh -c "open /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyphenex/ushyphex.tex"');` instead? (the positions of the quotes are swapped.) It works well on my end (Windows), so it's probably a Mac-specific thing from now on. :( which I don't think I'll be able to help. Hopefully the devs on Github can respond about this.

Comment: @Troy Great, this works! I'll try to add the rest and report back.

Comment: @Troy system('sh -c "open \`kpsewhich ushyphex.tex\`"'); also works :) It's getting closer ....

Comment: @samcarter Cool! :) The last part should be quite trivial then. Just a concatenation of strings.

Comment: @Troy Good that you mentioned "concatenation" !

Comment: @samcarter You can use 'app.load(path);'

Comment: @AfrendlyLee This sounds interesting! Can you please elaborate on this idea? Something like app.load(`kpsewhich ' + cursor.selectedText() + '`);'? (arg, the markup gets confused by the quotation marks, but I hope you get the idea.)

Comment: @samcarter I mean, you can use app.load(path) to open the file. You need to process more to have the path required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll be addressing the main question: **Is it possible to create a user macro (or similar) to open a file from the latex search path?**

Really, the whole issue is that TeXstudio does not (by default) involve the shell when executing its commands, which includes the `system(...)` command used in your user macro. 
This is outlined in the [TXS user manual](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION02a), under Section 1.3.2, Shell functionality.
So in order for your commands (denoted by `<cmds>` below) to run as they would in Terminal / Command Prompt, you would have to invoke shell explicitly in your user command:

For Mac OS / Linux:

```
sh -c "<cmds>"
```

For Windows:

```
cmd /C "<cmds>"
```

as per the User manual.

With that in mind, the rest is fairly simple: the result from `cursor.selectedText()` can just be concatenated as you would a string in the argument for `system(...)`.

---

In your case (Mac OS), something to this effect will suffice:

```
%SCRIPT
system('sh -c "open `kpsewhich ' + cursor.selectedText() + '`"')
```

Do note the placements of the quotes (single / double quotes) in the above command.