# Inlcude sub and subsubfolders \def\input@path does not work

Tags: texstudio

```
\makeatletter
\def\input@path{{figures}{tables}{chapters}}
\makeatother
```

does not work on my machine.
If I click on e.g. `\input{chapter_01}` where `chapter_01.tex` is a file in a subfolder. Compilation works fine, but not the goto function in texstudio.

Any idea?

Comment: as indicated by `@` it's a low level interface and while it's not impossible that editors know about it I'd be surprised if they know how to find files found by that method. Why not simply use `\input{chapters/chapter_01}` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It might seem trivial, but figures are always going to be in the figures folder, tables in the table folder, ... To work with latex should be as easy as possible :) If it's recursive, if it includes subfolders automatically, you can organize your folder structure much better as your project grows. You could start with a general chapter folder, and as soon as you have 10 sections, you can just move them into a subfolder `sections` without having to rewrite code.

Comment: I would probably just use `\input{chapter_01}` and arrange that `.//:` is in TEXINPUTS so it is found, but even then does texstudio find files that are input via TeX's search path? Not impossible but it is asking rather a lot of the editor it seems (TEXINPUTS would be easier for an editor as it can use kpsewhich to find the files, asking it to understand the tex macro coding to deduce the file location is harder)  It's purely an editor question though and I've never used texstudio so I can't help, sorry.

Comment: thanks for pointing me to TEXINPUTS, I read that before, but somehow It doesn't work for me. It was working on my old machine, I can't remember even setting this up... Thx for helping! =)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle TEXINPUT works now. Thank you! I deleted texstudio.ini set up the environment variable again and started TeXStudio. It worked like a charm!

Comment: I was a little bit hasty, it still only compiles. goto doesn't work ;)

Comment: the website suggests this which seems relevant https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/417727/create-texstudio-macro-to-open-file-from-tex-tree?rq=1